# Prove by Mean Value Theorem: $\frac15(b-a) < \arctan\left(1+\frac1a\right) - \arctan\left(1+\frac1a\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, mean-value-theorem

Prove
$$\frac15(b-a) < \arctan\left(1+\frac1a\right) - \arctan\left(1+\frac1b\right) < b-a; \qquad\text{ for }0<a<b<1.$$
I tried using the fact that arctan function is monotonous increasing but I simply couldn't solve it. I know that it might be easier using Taylor series around x=0 but there has to be a way only using the MVT.

Comment: Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: Another question about this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583095

Answer (score 0):

The mean-value theorem (MVT) states that under sufficient smoothness conditions for $f$ on the interval $(a,b)$, $0<a<b<1$, there exists a number $ \xi\in (a, b)$ such that

$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(\xi )(b-a)$$

Appliying the MVT to $f(x) =\arctan (1+\frac{1}{x})$ reveals that for some $
\xi\in (a,b)$

$$\arctan\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)-\arctan\left(1+\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{(b-a)}{\xi^2+(1+\xi)^2}$$

Then, since $0<\xi<1$, we have the inequalities

$$\frac15(b-a)<\frac{(b-a)}{\xi^2+(1+\xi)^2}<(b-a)$$

Comment: @admir Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)