# Lagrange theorem

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification

Using Lagrange theorem I need to prove :

$$\frac{b-a}{5}\lt \arctan\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right) - \arctan\left(1+\frac{1}{b}\right) \lt \left(b-a\right)   \tag{$0<a<b<1$}$$

So far I have come up to this but can't make a good connection between $\xi$ and the expression on the left. 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: This is my work.]

Comment: Let $x = b-a$. Then fix both sides as a function of x. Find that the limit for x tending to 0 for the function on the LHS is lower than the limit of the function on the RHS (for this, define the function at x =0: $f(0) = 0$). Then, find that both functions are differentiable in the interval (0,1) and prove that the derivative for the function on the left is strictly lower than the derivative of the fundtikn on the right for all x in said interval. Then, since they "start" with the same value at x=0, and since one always grows faster than the other, then LHS < RHS for all x in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x)=\arctan\left(1+\frac1x\right)$, then $f'(x)=-\frac1{2x^2+2x+1}$. So $x\in(0,1)\implies-1<f'(x)<-\frac15$. Therefore, by the Mean Value Theorem, if $0<a<b<1$,$$-1<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<-\frac15,$$which means that$$\frac{b-a}5<\arctan\left(1+\frac1a\right)-\arctan\left(1+\frac1b\right)<b-a.$$